# Twilio sms session between multiple website user pairs using app's twilio number

Tags: sms, twilio

I want to start and end session from my website where multiple users can start sms session from website and send message to mobile numbers using site's twilio number. the receiver then can reply to that message and sender user will get the sms on my website. I want to keep the conversation record for both parties.

Please suggest the best possible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got an answer from Twilio support as following and it is solving the problem at twilio end,

" I would recommend that you have a look at our Twilio chat blogpost at: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/06/build-your-own-agent-sms-chat-using-twilio-toll-free-numbers.html "

Mathew Jenkinson (Twilio)

Answer (score 2):

Twilio Evangelist here.

We call this Anonymous Communications and it is fairly easy to achieve. You have two different ways of approaching it:

**[REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest)**

When someone sends an SMS to your Twilio number, you respond to Twilio with empty [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml):

```
<Response></Response>
```

Then, you use the [helper library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries) in your preferred language to make an API call to Twilio to send a message to the counter-party. With the Ruby [helper library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/php/install), that would look like this (remember to change all the parameters as described):

```
require 'twilio-ruby'
client = Twilio::REST::Client.new "MY-TWILIO-SID", "MY-TWILIO_TOKEN"
client.account.messages.create to: "COUNTER-PARTY-NUMBER", from: "TWILIO-NUMBER", body: "MESSAGE-BODY"
```

If Ruby isn't your thing, we have libraries in [PHP](https://www.twilio.com/docs/php/install), [Python](https://www.twilio.com/docs/python/install), [C#](https://www.twilio.com/docs/csharp/install), [Java](https://www.twilio.com/docs/java/install) and [Node](https://www.twilio.com/docs/node/install). Plus a bunch more from our community.

Then the counter-party received the SMS, and replies. You just need to use their `From` number (the number of the person sending the message) to figure out who to send it back to - the original user - by looking up the session in your database.

**[TwiML Only](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml)**

The same thing can be achieved just using TwiML. When you create the TwiML response for the incoming SMS, you need to identify who the message should be sent to, just as before. Then you produce TwiML using some attributes on the [`<Message>` verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/message) (I'll use PHP this time):

```
<Response>
  <Message to="<?php echo $message_to; ?>" from="<?php echo $twilio_number; ">
    <?php echo $message_body ?>
  </Message>
</Response>
```

That will send the message on to the counter party, but you don't need to make an API call.

Hope this helps!